# Monitor network connection process / delay

Tags: macos, terminal, network, wifi

I'd like to identify what in the world delays my OSX 10.9.2 system from connecting to wifi upon waking from sleep. What is the right log to read or script to run or `netstat` or `lsof` command to run to figure out what's responsible for the delay?

I've twiddled with [energy settings](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5963) before and still occasionally get delayed 5-10 seconds.

While I've read a number of posts in a similar vein, I haven't found an answer yet.

Comment: what does your Console says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the level of detail I needed to find in `/var/log/system.log` where it outlines what's happening on the port.